# Detectar se um elemento contém uma classe com JavaScript puro

Tags: javascript

Em jQuery, temos o código

```
$("#elemento").hasClass("nomeDaClasse");
```

Que indica se um elemento contém determinada classe CSS. Como posso conseguir o mesmo com JavaScript puro?

Comment: Peço que não sejam feitas edições para adicionar tags como `jQuery`, já que a pergunta não é especificamente sobre a mesma e apenas a cita.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Nos navegadores modernos é possível usar a propriedade nativa *classList*, assim a *syntax* será:

```
div.classList.contains("foo");
```

[**Demonstração no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Xbhb/)

Esta "nova" [propriedade classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> é suportada a partir das seguintes versões:

- Chrome 8+;
- Firefox 3.6+;
- IE10+;
- Opera 11.5+;
- Safari 5.1+

---

Para usar javascript "antigo" também é possível usar por exemplo:

```
/**
 * Tem Classe
 * Verifica se o elemento do DOM tem determinada classe de CSS
 *
 * @param object el        Elemento do DOM
 * @param string classe    O nome da classe de CSS
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
function temClasse(el, classe) {
    return !!(el.className.split(' ').indexOf(classe) + 1);
}
```

[**Demonstração no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/S24eG/)

Answer (score 8):

Seu elemento possui a propriedade `className` que contém todas as classes ligadas ao mesmo. A partir daí, é possível criar uma função JavaScript simples para detectar se um elemento possui uma classe CSS:

```
function hasClass(elemento, classe) {
    return (' ' + elemento.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + classe + ' ') > -1;
}
```

Exemplo de utilização: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zBKCC/107/)

[Traduzido da questão original no SOEN, após eu resolver minha dúvida por lá](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5898748/1216805)

Answer (score 6):

Creio que esta seja a forma mais compatível com grande parte dos browsers e situações, além de permitir verificar mais de uma classe:

```
Node.prototype.hasClass = function(value) {
    var
        has = true,
        names = String(value).trim().split(/\s+/);

    for(var i = 0, len = names.length; i < len; i++){
        if(!(this.className.search(new RegExp('(?:\\s+|^)' + names[i] + '(?:\\s+|$)', 'i')) > -1)) {
            has = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return has;
};
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
element.hasClass('class-name');
```

Exemplo com mais de uma classe:

```
element.hasClass('class-name-a class-name-b');
```

Answer (score -3):

Você pode fazer de uma maneira bem simples

```
element.className.endsWith('class-name')
```

Exemplo:

```
        const element = document.getElementById('id-name')
        element.onclick = function() {

        if (element.className.endsWith('class-name')){
            console.log('OMG! CANT BELIEVE ITS WORKING')
        }
    }
```

Comment: Não funciona. O autor da pergunta quer saber se um elemento contém determinada classe CSS e não a string retornada por [Element.className](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/className) termina com uma determinada sting. ref->[String.prototype.endsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)