# If com tab active

Tags: javascript, html

gostaria de saber como faço um if com tab active em JavaScript

```html
<div class="nav-tabs-custom">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#negociosRealizados" data-toggle="tab" onclick="reload('negociosRealizados')">Negocios realizados</a></li>
    <li><a href="#baixados" data-toggle="tab" onclick="reload('baixados')">Baixados</a></li>
    <li><a href="#recomprados" data-toggle="tab" onclick="reload('recomprados')">Recomprados</a></li>
    <li><a href="#recompradosOp" data-toggle="tab" onclick="reload('recompradosOp')">Debitos Recomprados em Operação</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="active tab-pane" id="negociosRealizados">

    </div>
    <!-- /.tab-pane -->
    <div class="tab-pane" id="baixados">

    </div>
    <!-- /.tab-pane -->

    <div class="tab-pane" id="recomprados">

    </div>
    <!-- /.tab-pane -->

    <div class="tab-pane" id="recompradosOp">

    </div>
    <!-- /.tab-pane -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.tab-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.nav-tabs-custom -->
```

Por exemplo, if (negociosRealizados = active)

Comment: Quando você pretende fazer essa verificação? Em qual ação?

Comment: Uma maneira de trazer o id para uma função de JS, se o negocios realiazados estiver ativo, passa o id negocios realizados

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Detectar se um elemento contém uma classe com JavaScript puro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9605/detectar-se-um-elemento-cont%c3%a9m-uma-classe-com-javascript-puro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe uma forma simples de verificar a class de um elemento:

```
if(document.getElementById('negociosRealizados').classList.contains("active")){
    //codigo
}
```

Comment: O AP tem a necessidade no Javascript, essa solução contém o JQuery

Comment: Já editei, obrigado pela observação

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado :)

Comment: Ora essa, de nada :)

Answer (score 0):

Adiciona no seu código o js do bootstrap

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

O próprio bootstrap já trata o `active` e a mudança das abas

Lembra de verificar a versão do seu bootstrap.

Comment: E quanto ao if ?

Comment: Preciso que você elabore mais a pergunta especificando o que quer com o if, não ficou claro pra mim. Posta o js onde quer executar esse if e explique mais por favor

Comment: Você quer saber qual aba esta selecionada?